# How to create gradient at the top of the view

Tags: android, android-background

If you notice at the top of the View. There is a light gradient.

How should I go about creating this ?

e.g.

- Insert a view with a gradient background ?
- Use a top border of sorts ?

Any help would be great !

[image]

Comment: add an imageview that is a 9 patch image of that gradient (just a rectangle) and set the width to match parent. As long as you make the right side a stretchable patch it should do just this sort of gradient properly. That's the easiest way I think to do it

Answer (score 1):

create `gradient.xml` in `/res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes. I think this is what I need to do.